# Pagination plugin with AJAX using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I'm doing pagination with ajax using [pagination.js](https://pagination.js.org).

Everything is working fine except the "pageSize" property. I want to display 3 item per page but it is displaying all the data at once in the first page. How can I solve it?

I have attached my code here:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <div class="dataContainer"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    locator: "items",
    totalNumber: 20,
    pageSize: 5,
    pageRange: 2,
    ajax: {
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".dataContainer").html('Loading data from flickr.com ...');
        }
    },
    callback: function (data, pagination) {
        var html = simpleTemplating(data);
        $(".dataContainer").html(html);
    }
  });

  function simpleTemplating(data) {
    var html;
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        html = "running" + index;
    });
    return html;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `.pagination(`? It's not a built-in jQuery function. If you're using a plugin please specify its name and ideally also provide us with a link to its website and documentation. Otherwise it's hard for us to know what the function is actually supposed to do, or whether you have configured it correctly. You can't assume that we are all familiar with the specific thing you are using.

Comment: P.S. if you want to display 3 items per page then why did you set the page size to 5?

Comment: okay.. I referred  https://pagination.js.org/ website. sorry that's my mistake I want to display 3 item only but any way  if I  give `pageSize` whatever its displaying all data in every page.Actually the problem is  passing all data in callback property so i think there is some mistake so how to make based on page size.

Comment: thanks. So...you said "here displaying all the data in 1st page itself", but your code doesn't actually do that. It only displays one item (the last one) because in ` $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        html = "running" + index;
    });` you overwrite `html` each time. To get the behaviour you've described would require you to write `html += "running" + index;` instead. Please ensure any code you post here actually reproduces the issue you're talking about!

Comment: Clearly, doing that just inserts everything received, ignoring the pageSize instruction. It's not clear how, or if, the pageSize can actually be applied in this situation, except by you manually selecting the correct records to include in each page. But since the callback doesn't tell you the currently selected page number, I don't see how you can do that.

Comment: I guess you maybe got this code from a demo on their home page? They have demos using Flickr. Notice how both of those have the pageSize set as 20? Convenient for them, since Flickr's API always returns 20 records. It always returns the same 20 records - did you try moving through the pages on those demos? Each page shows the same 20 results. It just doesn't work.

Comment: It's unclear if this plugin actually works properly with an AJAX data source. It potentially works if the remote datasource accepts paging parameters (so the source works out which records to return) but this Flick endpoint doesn't do that. I think maybe the plugin also just isn't very good...

Comment: Thank you,  yes I took the code from plugin website only. Actually I had to do pagination in my project but i was not getting thats why i tried with that code seperately.  And I'm not good in this concept this is new for me . so can you please tell me how can do that if you know. is there any other solution?

Comment: well you could find a different plugin which actually works as intended, that would be my first piece of advice. Either that or you have to implement the paging logic yourself during the "callback" function. I've noticed that the `pagination` object does contain a `pageNumber` property which tells you what page is being shown (I was wrong about that before) so you could use that along with the page size to filter the `data` array to just the correct items

Comment: Okay , Thank you so much.

Comment: P.S. I figured out how to do the manual pagination - see answer below. If it helps you please remember to mark it "accepted" and/or give an upvote, thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you , its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this flickr API endpoint will always return exactly 20 items of its choosing and does not recognise any parameters instructing it to page the results, the assumptions behind pagination.js's logic do not work. The plugin appears to assume the data is returned already paged.

Therefore you need to implement pagination logic yourself inside the "callback" function. You can do this fairly easily using the pageNumber and pageSize variables supplied to the callback, and by slicing the results array appropriately. Here's a demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var container = $('#demo');
  container.pagination({
    dataSource: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    locator: 'items',
    totalNumber: 20,
    pageSize: 3,
    ajax: {
      beforeSend: function() {
        container.prev().html('Loading data from flickr.com ...');
      }
    },
    callback: function(response, pagination) {
      var dataHtml = '<ul>';
      var pageStart = (pagination.pageNumber - 1) * pagination.pageSize;
      var pageEnd = pageStart + pagination.pageSize;
      var pageItems = response.slice(pageStart, pageEnd);
      $.each(pageItems, function(index, item) {
        dataHtml += '<li>' + item.title + '</li>';
      });

      dataHtml += '</ul>';

      container.prev().html(dataHtml);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.1.4/pagination.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paginationjs/2.1.4/pagination.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <div class="data-container"></div>
    <div id="demo"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

N.B. This is a bit inefficient because it actually fetches all the data again from the API each time you move to a new page. You might be better to make your own AJAX request to the endpoint, get the returned data and pass it to the pagination plugin as a static array. Then you wouldn't need your own paging logic and you'd reduce the number of AJAX calls to one.